# libgdx table lays out components only in bottom right area

Tags: layout, libgdx

I'm using a Table to add some Labels to a stage. For some reason it adds it to the bottom right corner instead of the top left. Any ideas about how I can lay out the components correctly?

```
int dialogWidth = 450;
int dialogHeight = 650;

Label label1 = new Label("MUSIC:", skin);
Label label2 = new Label("SOUND EFFECTS:", skin);
Label label3 = new Label("JUMP SPEED:", skin);
TextButton btn1 = new TextButton("whatever", skin);

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Properties", skin);

dialog.setSize(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
dialog.setX(Helper.RESOLUTION_X_CENTER-dialogWidth/2);
dialog.setY(Helper.RESOLUTION_Y_CENTER-dialogHeight/2);

Table t = new Table();

t.setBounds(0, 0, dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

t.add(label1);
t.row();
t.add(label2);
t.add(btn1);
t.row();
t.add(label3);
dialog.add(t);
stage.addActor(dialog);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Fix 1:**

**Solution:** Remove the following line

```
t.setBounds(0, 0, dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
```

**Reason:** Don't use setBounds yourself. Let the layoutmanager handle it.

---

### **Fix 2:**

**Solution:** Replace the following line

```
dialog.add(t);
```

with

```
dialog.getContentTable().add(t).expand().left().top();
```

**Reason:** Dialog is itself a Table which contains 3 components viz Title, ContentTable, ButtonTable.
Your code was adding the new Table in the row of ButtonTable (last row hence at bottom) after ButtonTable (hence right).
The updated code adds it to the Content Table where it is supposed to be.
Refer to https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout to understand reason behind

```
expand().left().top();
```

---

Lastly, to debug any Table related issue, consider using debug lines (explained in the same link)
Hope this helps.